# Dart Angular Components Validator Example

Tags: angular, dart, components

Hello I am using Dart Angular Components. I try to use Number validators in the code:
  MaterialNumberValidator,
  PositiveNumValidator,
  CheckNonNegativeValidator,
  UpperBoundValidator
Could you provide an example how to use them in practice.

In component I added:

```
@Component(
   ...
  directives: const [
    CORE_DIRECTIVES,
    materialNumberInputDirectives,
    materialDirectives
  ],
  providers: const [NG_VALIDATORS]
)
```

In template I have.

```
  <material-input label="What do you need to do?"
                  autoFocus floatingLabel style="width:80%"
                  [(ngModel)]="newTodo"
                  (keyup.enter)="add()"
                  type="number"
                  checkInteger
                  checkPositive
                  >
  </material-input>
```

but It does not work.